# "Error binding parameter 0" using executemany()

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

`executemany()` fails to insert a datetime value. Error :

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Download EOD data from Yahoo
import sqlite3, datetime
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

con = sqlite3.connect('sec_master.db') 
now = datetime.datetime.now().date().isoformat()

# make it a dict and figure out how to ask for keys or values in 1 founction
def obtain_tickers():
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT ticker FROM securities")
        data = list(map(lambda x: x[0],cur.fetchall()))
        #data = dict(cur.fetchall())
        return data

def yf_request(ticker):
    data = yf.Ticker(ticker).history("max").reset_index()
    return data

def insert_into_db(data):
  column_str = """id, data_vendor_id, security_id, last_updated,date, open, high, low, close, volume, dividends, stock_split, returns""" 
  insert_str = ("?, " * 13)[:-2]
  final_str = "INSERT INTO daily_data (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (column_str, insert_str)  

  with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.executemany(final_str, data.values.tolist())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tickers = obtain_tickers()
    for t in tickers:
        yf_data = yf_request(t)
        insert_into_db(yf_data)
```

Comment: You need to examine the contents of the data before sending it to the database. Python supports far more datatypes than what can be sent to the database. You did not prepare the data, so its your responsibility to ensure that you don't attempt to bind arbitrary data. Have you heard of type hinting? Every variable should be annotated and you should use IDE capable of performing type checking. In this case, however, you have a runtime problem, which will not be caught by static check. Still, you need to have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a simple function check the type of each item before `insert_into_db()`, like

```
def check_type(yf):
  for thing in yf:
    print(f"the thing {thing} has type {type(thing)}")
```

Then call it here:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tickers = obtain_tickers()
    for t in tickers:
        yf_data = yf_request(t)
        check_type(yf_date)
        insert_into_db(yf_data)
```

Hypothetically, that will run for every t in tickets, but since you're getting the error it should only run once.

A big thing with Python is ensuring types are what they need to be because Python has dynamic typing, so a bug like this isn't a big surprise. You'll get good at dealing with it eventually. :)

Hope that's helpful. Update your post/comment with what your types are, if you can't make any progress.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful ! Needed to convert the date series to str before tolist() for it to work.